# Installing package dependencies on nitrous.io (Meteor's Android SDK)

Tags: android, meteor, nitrous

So right now I'm trying to install the Android SDK to test my Meteor app and play around with mobile development. "meteor install-sdk android" installs everything but the 32 bit libraries.

```
~/workspace$ meteor install-sdk android
```

✓ Found Android bundle
✓ A JDK is installed
✓ Found Android Platform tools
✓ Found Android Build Tools
✗ 32-bit libraries not found
✓ Found Android 19 API
✓ Found suitable Android x86 image
✓ 'meteor' android virtual device (AVD) found
✗ Android emulator acceleration is not installed
  (The Android emulator will be very slow without acceleration)
Platform requirements not yet met
Please follow the instructions here:
https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/Mobile-Dev-Install:-Android-on-Linux#libs32

So I try to apt-get it, but get a dpkg lock error.

### action@vigorous-trigger-81-209458:~/workspace$ sudo apt-get install --yes lib32z1

### WARNING: sudo access is not available; running without sudo.

E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?
action@vigorous-trigger-81-209458:~/workspace$ rm /var/lib/dpkg/lock
rm: remove write-protected regular empty file `/var/lib/dpkg/lock'? yes

rm: cannot remove`/var/lib/dpkg/lock': Permission denied

Is there any way that I can get these libraries installed on my Nitrous box so that I can run the android environment for Meteor?

Comment: You may want to email Nitrous support ( support@nitrous.io ) to see if there are any solutions to offering root access.

Answer (score 0):

We launched a new version of Nitrous called "Nitrous Pro" in April 2015 that has root access. You can check out some of the updates here:

https://pro.nitrous.io/whatsnew/